# Dynamic 'LIKE' Statement in SQL (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to select from a table with the following structure :

```
MATERIALS 
id
shortname 
longname
```

all the lines where the long name is like the short name.

I've tried the solution presented here : [Dynamic Like Statement in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612282/dynamic-like-statement-in-sql)
, but it doesn't work for me.

```
SELECT * from MATERIALS where longname like (shortname + '%');
```

doesn't work in Oracle.

Comment: I found the answer in the meantime : select * from materials where longname like CONCAT(upper(shortname), '%');

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the **[`CONCAT()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions026.htm#sthref1160)** function:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MATERIALS 
WHERE longname LIKE CONCAT(shortname, '%')
```

or even better, the standard **[`|| (double pipe)`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm)** operator:

```
SELECT * 
FROM MATERIALS 
WHERE longname LIKE (shortname || '%')
```

---

Oracle's `CONCAT()` function does not take more than 2 arguments so one would use the cumbersome `CONCAT(CONCAT(a, b), c)` while with the operator it's the simple: `a || b || c`

Answer (score 2):

`CONCAT()` is probably the most technically correct.

For convenience, however, ORACLE *does* have an equivalent operator to `+`...

```
SELECT * 
FROM MATERIALS 
WHERE longname LIKE (shortname || '%')
```

Comment: If I am not wrong `||` is the technically correct and `+` is non-standard.