# SELECT statement inside a LIKE

Tags: sql, oracle

I can't seem to shake of the error "missing right parenthesis" from 
this script.

```
INSERT INTO RECHARGES_TEMP_1
SELECT INT_SUBSCRIBER_ID,TRANS_DATE,FACE_VALUE,RECHARGE_COMMENT
FROM TDW.RECHG_HIST_DETAILS 
WHERE BALANCE_ID=1 
AND (RECHARGE_COMMENT LIKE '%785031357%'  (SELECT d.st,T.INT_SUBSCRIBER_ID SUB,'%''' 
                                           FROM TEMP_01 t, (select 'OR RECHARGE_COMMENT LIKE ''%' st from dual) d
                                           WHERE T.AREA LIKE 'Jaffna'))
AND TRANS_DATE BETWEEN 20161018 AND 20161019
```

inner select statement result:

```
OR RECHARGE_COMMENT LIKE '% 785049513   %'
OR RECHARGE_COMMENT LIKE '% 785049514   %'
OR RECHARGE_COMMENT LIKE '% 785049515   %'
OR RECHARGE_COMMENT LIKE '% 785049555   %'
OR RECHARGE_COMMENT LIKE '% 785049556   %'
OR RECHARGE_COMMENT LIKE '% 785049557   %'
OR RECHARGE_COMMENT LIKE '% 785049558   %'
OR RECHARGE_COMMENT LIKE '% 785049559   %'
OR RECHARGE_COMMENT LIKE '% 785049562   %'
OR RECHARGE_COMMENT LIKE '% 785049563   %'
OR RECHARGE_COMMENT LIKE '% 785049566   %'
OR RECHARGE_COMMENT LIKE '% 785049577   %'
```

Comment: That LIKE is very strange. What are you trying to do? Missing AND/OR?

Comment: You can't append SQL conditions like that. You would need dynamic SQL to do that (and: why are you storing dates as integers?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic 'LIKE' Statement in SQL (Oracle)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8327616/dynamic-like-statement-in-sql-oracle)

Answer (score 2):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do, but I *seems* as if you want something like this:

```
INSERT INTO recharges_temp_1
SELECT int_subscriber_id,trans_date,face_value,recharge_comment
FROM tdw.rechg_hist_details rhd
WHERE balance_id=1 
  AND exists (select 1 
              from TEMP_01 t
              where t.area = 'Jaffna'
               and instr(rhd.recharge_comment, t.int_subscriber_id) > 0)
  AND trans_date BETWEEN 20161018 AND 20161019
```

Comment: int_subscriber_id should be surrounded by spaces

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: I don't think so, because the concatenation in the original statement does not add any spaces.

Comment: `OR RECHARGE_COMMENT LIKE '% 785049513   %'`

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz: but this: `LIKE ''%'` does not add any spaces.

Comment: Also you have to add `RECHARGE_COMMENT LIKE '%785031357%'`

Comment: Maybe the INT_SUBSCRIBER_ID  contain leading space + trilling spaces / is of time char

Comment: the RECHARGE_COMMENT LIKE '%785031357%' is to avoid the 'or' statement at the begining, there is no spaces required for int_subscriber_id. Its very basic, all i want is to continue the

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO RECHARGES_TEMP_1
SELECT      INT_SUBSCRIBER_ID,TRANS_DATE,FACE_VALUE,RECHARGE_COMMENT
FROM        TDW.RECHG_HIST_DETAILS 
WHERE       BALANCE_ID=1 
        AND (RECHARGE_COMMENT LIKE '%785031357%'

            or  exists 
                (
                  SELECT    null
                  FROM      TEMP_01 t                              
                  WHERE     T.AREA = 'Jaffna'
                       and  RECHARGE_COMMENT like '%' || trim (T.INT_SUBSCRIBER_ID) || '%'
                )
            )

        AND TRANS_DATE BETWEEN date '2016-10-18' AND date '2016-10-19'
;
```

P.s.

- I'm guessing TRANS_DATE is a date and not an integer
- You should be aware to the space surrounding INT_SUBSCRIBER_ID