# SQL LIKE Concerns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I would like to ask if is there a way I can achieve this query:

```
Select *
from table1 
where table1.column1 like '%' (Select  table2.column1 from table2)
```

where `table2` contains all the values being compared in the `like` statement.

Is there a way that I can achieve this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic Like Statement in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612282/dynamic-like-statement-in-sql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
Select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1
              from table2 t2
              where t1.column1 like '%' + t2.column1
             );
```

Comment: well, does the performance of the query change when it try to fetch to tables with large data?

Comment: @user3312649 . . . Because this is an inefficient way of doing the comparison.  Every row in `t1` has to be compared to many rows in `t2` (up to the first matching row or all if none match).  Because of the `'%'` at the beginning of the `like` pattern, there is no simple way to fix this problem.

Comment: ahhh.. so i see if it will fetch large data it will really slow down.. am i right?

Comment: @user3312649 . . . Yes.  If performance is an issue, you can ask another question, with more details about the sizes of the tables, the data layouts, and examples of matches you are looking for.

Comment: nahh , i think you have provided me enough solution.. hehe thanks.